# Big-O, Big-Omega, Θ notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What is the **Big-O**, **Big-Omega** and **Theta (Θ)** notation for the function,
**5 + 2sin(n)**

Answer (score 2):

Since *5 + 2sin(n)* is bounded by a constant value both above a below, it holds that *5 + 2sin(n) = O(1)*. It also holds that it is *Ω(1)*. Since it is both, it is also *Θ(1)*.

You can show this more formally by finding the values between which your function is bounded, and using the definitions of Big-O and Big-Omega.